# More than one line of code in ternary statement?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have more than one "line of code" after the `:`? Currently, `clearNameInputRef.current.style.display = "none";` is running regardless, but it should only run if `searchName == ""`/if `searchName != ""` is `false`

```
searchName != "" ? fetchClassesByName() : nameDropdownRef.current.style.display = "none"; clearNameInputRef.current.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a regular `if`/`else` construct? That's also easier to read and debug

Comment: Use a method to run more complex operations in a ternary statement.

Comment: Don't try hard to use ternarys. If it's not convenient, don't use them. if / else are perfectly fine, and readability should always be the highest priority.

Comment: The purpose ternary operator is to return something. If it's not returning anything, or you don't care about it then don't use that and use plain if-else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add new-lines after `?` or `:` for *lines of code*.

No, you cannot have multiple *expressions* inside the "`:` block".

> Currently ... is running regardless

Because the semi-colon ended the ternary, and the else-expression.

You'd need to use a single expression in the else part, like a method.

```
searchName != "" ? fetchClassesByName() : ClearStyles(nameDropdownRef.current.style, clearNameInputRef.current.style);

...

private void ClearStyles(... s1 , ... s2) {  // Not sure what types these are
    s1.display = "none"; 
    s2.display = "none";
}
```

However, ternaries are meant to return a conditional value, not run two methods conditionally, so use an actual if-else.